# JDBC : How to write the result set to a table without a pojo?

Tags: jdbc, resultset

I have a remote table which gets updated daily. I need to fetch the new rows and insert in my local table. I wish to achieve this without using a POJO for the table so that the whole process is fast as well scalable to accommodate any more tables that I may need to add to this process.
Is it possible to eliminate the POJO ? Will it be more efficient than using a POJO ?
Including the code that I have written:

```
int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        if(rs.next())
        {
            aListObj= new ArrayList<String>() ;
            for(int i=1 ; i <= columnCount ; i++)
                aListObj.add(rs.getObject(i).toString());   
        }else
        {
            if(rs != null)
                rs.close();
            if(srcConn != null )
                srcConn.close();

        }
        return aListObj ;
```

Comment: what you have done so far!! any code ?

Comment: Why on earth do you think that using a POJO to hold the content of each row would be slower or less scalable than using an ArrayList? It won't. And at least, it will be readable and maintainable: is it easier to know what to do when getting a City instance with 4 fields id, name, population and countryId, or when getting an ArrayList with 4 elements?

Comment: well, the reason to not use POJO is that , the table structure can change frequently, often adding new columns.
Moreover the data I have is like 15 tables with 30-60 columns in each so it will be cumbersome to call a lot of setters.

Comment: The solution which I am trying to get at is to create an in-memory csv representation of data so that disk I/O can be saved.